# How do I implement expandable List view setOnItemClickListener from button present in child view?

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am trying to figure out how to implement expandable List view setOnItemClickListener from button present in child view. Here's what I have so far:

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.weekly_event_child_items, null);
    }

    Button mybutton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    mybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v1) {
            ((ExpandableListView) parents).performItemClick(v1,positions, 0);
        }
    });
}
```

In main view I have implemented:

```
expandableListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        System.out.println("clicked");
    }
});
```

I am expecting ((ExpandableListView) parents).performItemClick(v1,positions, 0 this to somehow make a call to the event handler in expandableListView.setOnItemClickListener, which is currently not happening. I want to make a call from a button click present in child view to make a call to expandable listview's item click listener.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? What is the result of the code you've posted here and what are the results you were expecting? (Depending on what you're asking logs may be helpful as well).

Comment: I am expecting ((ExpandableListView) parents).performItemClick(v1,positions, 0 this to somehow make a call to 
 expandableListView.setOnItemClickListener which is not happening. I want to make a call from a button click present in child view to make a call to expandable listview  setOnItemClickListener.

Comment: What happens now? Is there an exception when you do ((ExpandableListView) parents).performItemClick(v1,positions, 0); or does it get called successfully and just not do anything? Incidentally, is "parent" null at this point? I don't see where you're setting this. I think you probably don't want to use that variable at this point, you'll probably want a different way of retrieving the expandable list. Why not just get the expandable list with another FindViewById call?

Comment: Also, is this the complete code? I don't see anything being returned from the method you posted - I wouldn't expect that this would even compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the method below:

```
public void onClick(View v1) {
    ((ExpandableListView) parents).performItemClick(v1,positions, 0);
}
```

isn't implemented properly. If you're doing an operation with the ExpandableListView, you can just retrieve it with FindViewById(...).

I think that this is also the incorrect place to set the button event listener, since it's not specifically related to the individual child views.

Comment: i am not getting any exception but the setOnItemClickListener not getting called

Comment: setOnItemClickListener itself shouldn't be called - all it does is *set* the onItemClickListener. It itself isn't the event handler.